# Matlab Differential Equations Euler’s method

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I need help plotting a differential equation ... it keeps coming out all funky and the graph is not what it's supposed to look like.

```
function [dydt] = diff(y,t)

dydt = (-3*y)+(t*(exp(-3*t)));

end

tI = 0;
yI = -0.1;
tEnd = 5;
dt = 0.5;

t = tI:dt:tEnd;
y = zeros(size(t));
y(1) = yI;

for k = 2:numel(y)
    yPrime = diff(t(k-1),y(k-1));
    y(k) = y(k-1) + dt*yPrime;
end

plot(t,y)
grid on
title('Engr')
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('y(t)')
legend(['dt = ' num2str(dt)])
```

That's my code, but the graph is not anything like what it's supposed to look like. Am I missing something like an index for the `for` statement?

**Edit**

I am getting an error:

```
Error using diff
Difference order N must be a positive integer scalar.

Error in diff3 (line 12)
    yPrime = diff(t(k-1),y(k-1));
```

Comment: You have problems with function names: matlab already have build-in function 'diff' and try to call this function instead your own function. Try to use different name for your function 'diff'.

Comment: Your other problem is that your ODE function is defined as `diff(y,t)` but you're calling with the arguments flipped: `diff(t(k-1),y(k-1))`. I'd recommend following what Matlab's ODE solvers do (e.g., `ode45`) and defining your ODE function's arguments as `t`, and then `y`. You'll also find out that your time-step, `dt`, is too large, even for this simple function. Try 0.1 or less.

Comment: You're also going to want your ODE function to be a sub-function (or a separate M-file function) rather than being that the beginning of your code as you have it shown here.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the errors pointed out by Danil Asotsky and  horchler in the comments:

1. avoiding name conflict with  built-in function 'diff'
2. changing the order of arguments to `t,y`.
3. decreasing the time-step `dt` to 0.1
4. converting ODE right-hand side to an anonymous function

(and removing unnecessary parentheses in the function definition), your code could look like this:

```
F = @(t,y) -3*y+t*exp(-3*t);

tI = 0;
yI = -0.1;
tEnd = 5;
dt = 0.1;

t = tI:dt:tEnd;
y = zeros(size(t));
y(1) = yI;

for k = 2:numel(y)
    yPrime = F(t(k-1),y(k-1));
    y(k) = y(k-1) + dt*yPrime;
end

plot(t,y)
grid on
title('Engr')
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('y(t)')
legend(['dt = ' num2str(dt)])
```

which performs as expected:

[image: output]